# iOS Programming with GCD

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I use GCD to fetch some images from the Internet in a new queue using `dispatch_queueu_create`. Then I go back to the main queue and update the `UIImageView` with the fetched image by using `dispatch_async`. I am using `self.imageView` to reference to the `UIImageView` in the main queue.

However, sometimes the image takes some time to load from the Internet. If the user clicks somewhere and the view controller changes to something else, I found some weird behavior or my app even crashes. I guess the reason is that I am referencing to self.imageView but the current view controller doesn't have that property. Or any other possibilities? Any suggestions to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

---

Sorry that I didn't include code here. Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    dispatch_queue_t photoFetchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("photo data downloader", NULL);
    dispatch_async(photoFetchQueue, ^{
        NSURL *photoURL = ...;
        NSData *photoData = ...;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
            self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);
            self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
            self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
            [scrollView zoomToRect:imageView.frame animated:YES];
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(photoFetchQueue);
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what you are doing wrong without sources, don't you think?

Comment: You should consider using NSOperations and NSOperationQueue.

Comment: Till: I was too rush to post the code. But you are right. The cost is posted. Thanks.
AnkitSrivastava: Code posted. Thanks.
titaniumdecoy: I know NSOperations and NSOperationQueue should work as well but I am doing it in GCD. Any idea how to do so in GCD? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a cancellation pattern.   That is, you need to be able to cancel the background task.   Without code, hard to say what the best approach would be.   If you used the higher level NSOperation API, it has cancellation support.

For Blocks/GCD, you'd probably want to have an "isCanceled" on some object somewhere -- preferably on the object that represents the background fetch -- and then check that, when possible, to determine if the response is still relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am doing it in GCD. The code is posted. Can you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: BTW I thought of a way. Is it OK to simply check if (self.view.window) before the UI updates?

Comment: Sure -- make sure you check for `nil` in the main thread or else you'll end up w/a race condition.

Comment: Thanks bbum. Now my app runs smoothly without crashing and weird behavior anymore.